# How to control which category will be picked for the slug of a post?

Tags: posts, categories, permalinks, slug

I'm using the permalink structure "/%category%/%postname%/".

What bothers me is that I have posts that belong to two categories. And of course, unfortunately, Wordpress always picks the wrong one for the slug generation.

Is there a nice and clean way of having control on which category will be chosen for the post slugs?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress picks the lowest ID as its main permalink. However, **ALL** categories will contain your post automatically. Meaning both these:

- http://yoursite/category-A/post-A
- http://yoursite/category-B/post-A

...will return your post (given that post-A is in both category-A and category-B) via a redirect. It can't list them all to you on the Edit page, sorry. But it will make sure they're available in all categories.

Of course, [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) will return the wrong one for you.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.25category.25_with_multiple_categories_on_a_post

Now as for overriding the behavior, look at:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/link-template.php#L71, specifically a little lower on line 121. It's going to use `$cats[0]->slug` after sorting by ID. Which does not appear to be hookable in any way inside there, so either higher or lower.

This is a ticket that was going to change the way it worked http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18752 it's marked for *Future Release*, though. Subscribe to the ticket to show your interest, maybe it makes it into WordPress 3.5 later this year.

The [`pre_post_link`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/link-template.php#L115) filter will allow you to override the permalink. [`post_link`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/link-template.php#L163), too.

Alternatively, [`get_the_category`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L65), should allow you to hack the IDs for a post (or remove the others to leave only one), but this should **only** occur when the permalink is requested.

```
add_filter( 'pre_post_link', function( $permalink, $post ) {

     if ( strpos($permalink, '%category%') === false )
         return; /* not interested */
     add_filter( 'get_the_categories', 'wpse46860_prune_categories' );
     return $permalink;

}, null, 2 );

function wpse46860_prune_categories( $categories ) {

    /* run once */
    remove_filter( 'get_the_categories', 'wpse46860_prune_categories' );

    /* .. prune the categories to leave the one you need .. */
    global $_hijack_post_id;

    return $categories;

}
```

This is a hack.

An additional difficulty is to get the post_ID to prune the categories against, the `get_the_categories` filter does not pass the post_ID to us; use a global (dirty) or a class property (clean).

You can try out different permalink plugins like:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-permalinks/screenshots/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, this stuff gets me a little confused after awhile. Cheers!

Comment: I knew that, and a few months ago I re-created my categories to have them "in order". But now I have many posts and many categories, and I wondered if there was a plugin for that?

Comment: @TigrouMeow I'm updating the answer little by little in search for a good solution. There appear to be no plugins for this. Except maybe http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/ which is isn't too nice.

Comment: That could be a good hack. I could maintain a list of categories to exclude (as an option in my theme for example) and use it in this second function. But again, if can I assign very high IDs easily to those categories, the final result will be the same, and I wouldn't have do any kind of hacks...

Comment: @TigrouMeow, so the short answer appears to be "not yet", http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18752 was supposed to handle this, still waiting. Other than that hope my hacks helped you understand how it all works.

Comment: @TigrouMeow, I don't see how high IDs would help with intersecting categories. This is purely a matter of pruning the right ID (stored in post meta data for example) out of the many you have, faking as if the only category the post belongs to is the one you need. The category IDs have to be managed (pruned) on a per-post basis, you can't expect all posts to rely on a predefined ID order of the categories. Post A may want to have Category B and Post B may want to have category A, though both posts are in both categories.

Comment: Thanks yeah, that explains really everything very well :) Many ways of going around that issue are fighting into my little head now...

Comment: @Soulseekah Actually in my case, here wouldn't be issue, I could rely on the order brought by the category IDs. I have distinct categories, used for the permalink, and the others are kind of "tags" (but they have to be treated as categories). An example of this "tag" category is "Best of".

Answer (score 1):

You can always go with a plugin. [Hikari Category Permalink](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hikari-category-permalink/) does exactly what you are looking for... with no hassle.

Comment: Super plugin! That's actually what I was looking for. Really clean and convenient. I hope it will be kept updated though, as I don't know how it operates exactly. Thanks for this :)

Answer (score 0):

IF you can save Which category you want as default permalink, then you can hook into get_permalink function using "pre_post_link" filter....

This might also help, give a look..
http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-permalink-add